# Как добавить обработчик отправки формы в цикле сразу нескольким формам?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы этот обработчик был присвоен к каждой форме с определённым классом. Но при заходе на страничку, где расположен этот rод с циклом для всех форм, строка `voteForm.submit(function(event)` автоматически отправляет запрос post без полезной информации на сервер, сервер возвращает заглушку и браузер редиректится на эту заглушку, вместо того, чтобы вызвать `posting.done(function( data )`. *Т.е. отправка формы инициируется кодом, а не юзером*: юзер переходит на страничку, та почти моментально редиректится на заглушку.

```js
var voteForms = $( ".voteForm" )
// добавляем каждой форме с классом voteForm этот обработчик:
for (var i = 0; i < voteForms.length; i++) {
    // присваиваем обработчик отправки формы
    voteForm = voteForms[i]
    voteForm.submit(function(event) {
        // останавливаем обычную отправку с перезагрузкой страницы
        event.preventDefault();

        // вытаскиваем url
        var $form = $( this );
        var url = $form.attr( 'action' );

        // отправка данных
        var posting = $.post( url, voteForm.serialize() );

        // действия после получения ответа от сервера
        posting.done(function( data ) {
          alert('success');
        });
    });
}
```

Код для одной конкретной формы работает правильно: при отправке формы юзером вызывает `posting.done(function( data )`.

```js
// присваиваем обработчик отправки формы
voteForm = $("#poll2")
voteForm.submit(function(event) {
    // останавливаем обычную отправку с перезагрузкой страницы
    event.preventDefault();

    // вытаскиваем url
    var $form = $( this );
    var url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    // отправка данных
    var posting = $.post( url, voteForm.serialize() );

    // действия после получения ответа от сервера
    posting.done(function( data ) {
      alert('success');
    });
});
```

В чём ошибка? Как присвоить этот обработчик нескольким формам по классу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`voteForms[i]` возвращает DOM-элемент.

```
$(voteForm).submit(function(event) { // а не voteForm.submit
  ...
  var posting = $.post( url, $form.serialize() ); // а не voteForm.serialize()
```